# How to make a .crx file installer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, installation

I have made many CRX files for Google Chrome, and I was wondering if there was a way for someone to download the CRX file from my website and have it automatically installed (like it does for the Chrome Webstore)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a special API from Google to install applications and extensions inline from your website. However, it is still hosted in the Chrome Web Store. The advantage is that user doesn't have to leave your website. It is called **chrome.webstore API**.

Nice read about API itself:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore.html

More about **inline installation**:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation.